# Vector size increases only by one when insert with multiple elements

Tags: c++, vector, insert

I'm currently learning C++ and for my current goal I want to fill values from `vector A` into `vector X`. `vector X` must not be larger than 20. To archive this I have a function that checks if the current vector has space left. If no space is left, it replaces the current vector with a new vector from a template (which already contains some entries, that have to be the same for all the vectors):

```cpp
int ChunkedBufferBuilder::checkNewBuffer() {
  int space_left = chunk_size - super::current.size();
  if (space_left == 0) {
    bufVec.push_back(super::current);
    super::current = tpl;
    space_left = chunk_size - super::current.size() ;
  }

  return space_left;
}
```

`bufVec` is another vector holding all vectors that have reached a size of 20. This function returns always the remaining amount of "free" entries in the current Vector.

To prevent having to insert every single value from the input vector in to the smaller vectors, I'm trying to use the `insert` function here:

```cpp
ChunkedBufferBuilder* ChunkedBufferBuilder::push_back(const std::vector<uint8_t> &vec) {
  auto pos = 0;
  const auto size = vec.size();

  while (pos < size) {
    const int space_left = checkNewBuffer();
    const int to = (space_left > size - pos) ? size : pos + space_left;
    auto fromPtr = vec.at(pos);
    auto toPtr = vec.at(to);

    int size = super::current.size();

    super::current.insert(super::current.end(), fromPtr, toPtr);

    size = super::current.size();

    pos = to;
  }

  return this;
}
```

Note, that the second `size = super::current.size()` was placed there by me for helping to debug. In the following images I have set two breakpoints. One on the line where `insert` is called and the other one on the `pos = to` assignment.

The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) of `std::vector` states that:

> The vector is extended by inserting new elements before the element at the specified position, **effectively increasing the container size by the number of elements inserted.**

Thus I expect that the size increases by the amount of elements, that I added. But when I run the debugger:

I get these values at the first breakpoint:
[image: Values of first breakpoint]

And at the second breakpoint `size` only increased by one:
[image: Values of second breakpoint]

However on the second pass of the while loop, it then tries to insert another twelve values (`size` is still 8 so `20 - 8 == 12`):
[image: Values of first breakpoint (second pass)]

And then suddenly the size jumps to 22:
[image: Values of second breakpoint (second pass)]

This is currently breaking my program and I'm pretty much clueless why my code behaves in the way it currently does.

Comment: `fromPtr` and `toPtr` are not pointers. They are the values in the vector found at indexes `pos` and `to`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this snippet:

```
auto fromPtr = vec.at(pos);
auto toPtr = vec.at(to);

super::current.insert(super::current.end(), fromPtr, toPtr);
```

you are [inserting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) `fromPtr` copies of the value `toPtr` (i.e. overload (3)). From your description, it appears you mean to use overload (4):

```
super::current.insert(super::current.end(), vec + pos, vec + to);
```

which copies elements from `vec` to `super::current`.

Comment: Oh wow. My bad. I've read the whole insert documentation over and over again but did not read the documentation about at. Thank you for the quick response!